# Make an image dissapear using CSS without hover

Tags: html, css, animation

So I'm working on an email for work that shows a bunch of shirts. Since the tagline is "get them before they're gone," I've been asked to animate each shirt disappearing one by one until they're, well, gone.

Everything I know and/or have found only works on hover, which I don't want. I'd like it to start automatically by itself.

So I don't look entirely lazy, here is some starter code for `jsfiddle`. Once I see how one shirt is coded, I can probably figure out the rest timing wise and such. Thanks in advanced to anyone that can help!

Note: Pretend this doesn't have to do with email - I've been asked to explore it, even if it doesn't work and we decide to just use an animated gif.

```
<html>
   <head>
      <style type="text/css">
      </style>
   </head>
   <body>
      <img alt="shirt" src="https://s7.jcrew.com/is/image/jcrew/60763_WW8415?$pdp_fs418$" />
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why not use an animated gif?

Comment: We've used animated gifs in the past, but since my team came back from the Litmus conference this week they received information that CSS3 animations were the way to go (which I agree), especially since they're less big file wise. So they wanted me to look into it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your audience is using modern email clients, that support css3 try using it. [More](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_animations)

Using CSS3: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dosd8vae/)

```
img {
    animation: Gone 5s 1;
    opacity: 0;
}

@keyframes Gone {
  0%   { opacity: 1; }
  100% { opacity: 0; }
}
```

Else use animated gif for it.

Comment: Absolutely perfect. Exactly what I needed. Thank you so much!

Comment: Use the -webkit prefix for browsers using the webkit engine.

Answer (score 3):

`:hover` is not consistently supported across email clients, nor is CSS animation. JavaScript is not supported either - so the best you can probably do in an animated GIF, and even there, there's no guarantee that the user's mail client will support that.

See: http://litmus.com/blog/a-guide-to-animated-gifs-in-email

https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/

Comment: I've found it's supported in most of the major email clients except Outlook, but Outlook doesn't support animated gifs anyway so we're okay with those customers receiving non-animated versions.

Even if we find it's not ideal, I've still been asked to try

Answer (score 0):

Don't use javascript as non-web based mail clients won't be able to run it (and the web based ones will probably block it). Use animated gif images where the t-shirts disappear after 2s, 4s, 6s, and so on.

Comment: Yeah, JS is a no-go, but I have still be asked to explore this option, even if we decided to go back to the gif. 

Just pretend I didn't say email haha